# Varying windowSoftInputMode for fragments inside the viewpager

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager with 2 different fragments.
For the first fragment, I would like to define it so that it does not resize upon the soft keyboard opening.
For the second fragment, I would like to have it resize.

Setting the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` inside the manifest will work for both fragments, but I want to vary it between the two.

What I've done after google searches :

```
    // create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.NoResize);
    // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(context);
    // inflate using the cloned inflater, not the passed in default
    return localInflater.inflate.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,container,false);
```

I've custom defined the theme to be :

```
<style name="NoResize" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

The activity is defined with default windowSoftInputMode which resizes the views when softkeyboard opens up.

Will be working on this until it gets solved but if anyone else has this problem and solved it, it would be awesome to hear any thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: found any solution ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can call on each onCreateView

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE

In my case, this doesn't solve the problem, because I have a transparent Fragment (a chat window) which I need to resize and the fragment on the bottom shouldn't. but I think it could be useful to you.

Comment: Moxor, I do not quite understand what problem you are having, but you may wish to open your own question in order to describe it in more detail. For the question asked here - changing the window's soft input mode - your answer is correct. There may be cases such as yours where the window's soft input mode isn't sufficient, but there is no single solution to all such cases; it's going to depend on the nature of your particular problem.

Comment: Thanks, I probably will open a new question. My particular issue was having two visible Fragments at the same time, and expecting different behaviour for each one

Comment: Seems like this method starts working only after you define any value in AndroidManifest explicitly. 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
Moreover, this value should differ from `adjustUnspecified`. Without this explicit definition `setSoftInputMode(...)` method will have no effect.