# How to set windowsSoftInputMode from fragment

Tags: android

How to change windowsSoftInputMode from fragment ?

I already try to set with this line of code

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

I need this input type just for single fragment, when I try from manifest for whole activity everything work perfectly .

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling this line of code?  You can set it from onCreateView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421857/varying-windowsoftinputmode-for-fragments-inside-the-viewpager

Comment: I have try this in onCreateView()